# how do I reference location of .my.cnf in bash/mysql script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I have a bash script that connects to a mysql server and pulls information. I have my .my.cnf file in my home directory. I want to change the location of the .cnf file to ~myname/.my.cnf

My question is how do I reference this new location in my script or in my mysql call to the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "~myname/.my.cnf". This would expand to a directory made of a concatenation of your username and "myname" which doesn't make any sense. I guess you might mean "~/something/.my.cnf"

The '~' [expands to $HOME](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) hence simply redefining $HOME before invoking mysql should suffice (although this will confuse further references to '~'.

```
HOME=$HOME/myname
mysql <somescript.sql
```

Comment: youre correct about the location ~/something/.my.cnf . Sorry for my error. I will try and add this to the script and see how it works out to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the doc reference for how MySQL looks at Options Files: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

```
File Name   Purpose
/etc/my.cnf Global options
/etc/mysql/my.cnf   Global options
SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf   Global options
$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf  Server-specific options (server only)
defaults-extra-file The file specified with --defaults-extra-file, if any
~/.my.cnf   User-specific options
~/.mylogin.cnf  User-specific login path options (clients only)
```

Note: you want to use `defaults-extra-file` option when connecting with mysql client.  `mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/path/to/file/.filename < script`

You should consider using `--login-path` as an alternative. [Login path reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_login-path).  The file is not plain text.  You use `mysql_config_editor` to create your login paths, which stores username, password, host, etc.